# Front, back and bottom orthographic view do not match

Tags: camera, orthographic

I found this starship blueprint on internet:

[image: Enterprise blueprint]

I would like to start working on it from the warp drive.

I am using the blueprint as background image, but front, back and bottom  orthographic view do not match. I will try to explain my problem with an example.

A good starting point to make the warp drive is from a cylinder, using the cursor as point of view. I made it match the blueprint using the bottom view.

[image]

Then, since front and view were "broken", I rotated the cylinder again to match the blueprint.

[image]

But, as you can see, front and back view are perfect, but bottom view is broken.

I cannot make my cylinder match the blueprint position- and rotation-wise.

How can I solve this problem? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of "front", "back" and "bottom" in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some useful controls on the *Background Images*, Giovarco, that could solve Your problem. As You could see on the image below in the green rectangle, You could **rotate** and **move** the image using X, Y and ROTATION parameters so **You have to rotate the TOP view 90 degrees** and then use the X and Y parameters to line it up. Hope it helps buddy.

[image]

Sincerely, Jan